# Installation error in with byteflow-0.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.6, django-1.3

I am installing byteflow-0.7 on python 2.6.5 with django 1.3 on windows7(64-bits). Database used is MySQL 5.0.51b on wamp 2.0 server. I installed all the prerequisites well and have run the syncdb command. That run well and the database was created successfully. When I run the server and hit the localhost:8000 on my browser, I see the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "D:\djangowork\piranha-byteflow-98c3681f5a8f\apps\pingback\middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
    class PingbackMiddleware(object):

  File "D:\djangowork\piranha-byteflow-98c3681f5a8f\apps\pingback\middleware.py", line 4, in PingbackMiddleware
    xmlrpc_url = reverse('xmlrpc')

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 391, in reverse
    *args, **kwargs)))

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 312, in reverse
    possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 229, in _get_reverse_dict
    self._populate()

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 197, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 279, in _get_url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 274, in _get_urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "D:\djangowork\piranha-byteflow-98c3681f5a8f\urls.py", line 45, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root, name='admin'),

AttributeError: 'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'root'
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `AdminSite.root` had been marked deprecated in Django 1.1 and apparently it is now removed in Django 1.3. So you either have to downgrade Django to 1.0 (as this is what ByteFlow website says in requirements) or use a newer Byteflow version that has this issue fixed.

PS. Found a [fix](https://bitbucket.org/tehfink/byteflow/changeset/2bb278780d35) in a [forked repo](https://bitbucket.org/tehfink/byteflow).